# Is it possible to create a graph database using AQL in Arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

It seems the options to create a graph within Arangodb are:

1. The Web Interface
2. [Arangosh using the general-graph module](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Management.html)
3. [The provided drivers using the object based API](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-drivers/)
4. [The HTTP API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/HTTP/index.html)

Is it possible to create the necessary components to build a graph using AQL???

For background, I am trying to assess options for bootstrapping graphs in different environments and potentially performing migrations in production environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, at the moment AQL is only a DML (data manipulation language), but no DDL (data definition language).
To create a graph, please use one of the other methods you listed.

Comment: many thanks, we would like to create graphs in our database on "startup", potentially from csv files.  Is arangosh able to read in files using something like 'fs' or would we be better using the npm module to load the data from the filesystem and create node based scripts to bootstrap our graphs?  thanks!

Comment: arangosh can do it in general, though it will not be as flexible as using node.js with all of its available modules/tools. For file handling in arangosh, there are `require("fs").readFileSync()` and `require("internal").processCsvFile()`, but if they are not flexible enough for your demands, it may be better to fall back to a general solution that employs node.js to do the file processing and data loading.